# Flutter Firebase - Snapshot cannot get data,

Tags: android, flutter, dart

If I am trying to get data for example `snapshot.data.lenght` it does not work (it is not even displaying at as possible if I press tab) and I get the following error:

**The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState>#7a7e2):
Class 'List' has no instance getter 'documents'.
Receiver: Instance(length:2) of '_GrowableList'
Tried calling: documents**

My code:

```
  Future<List> _getPlants() async {
var firestore = Firestore.instance;
QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore.collection("easy_plants").getDocuments();
List<PlantsMainItem> plantsmainnew = [];
for (int i = 0; i < qn.documents.length; i++) {
  var a = qn.documents[i];
  PlantsMainItem plantsitem = PlantsMainItem(
      a.data["title"],
      a.data["titlelatin"],
      a.data["content"],
      NetworkImage(a.data["image"]),
      a.data["sunlevel"],
      a.data["level"]);

  print(plantsitem.titlelatin);
  plantsmainnew.add(plantsitem);

}
//print(plantsmainnew.length);
return plantsmainnew;
```

}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {

```
return Container(
  child: FutureBuilder(
        future: _getPlants(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.data == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Container(
              height: 200,
              width: 400,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Center(
                  child: Container(
                    child: LinearProgressIndicator(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            print(snapshot.data);
            return Text("TEST", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30));

          }

        }
  ),
);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error say that your "List" class has no documents getter, can you try same code with delete "List" from your function?

```
Future _getPlants() async {
  var firestore = Firestore.instance;
  QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore.collection("easy_plants").getDocuments();
  List<PlantsMainItem> plantsmainnew = [];
  for (int i = 0; i < qn.documents.length; i++) {
    var a = qn.documents[i];
    PlantsMainItem plantsitem = PlantsMainItem(
      a.data["title"],
      a.data["titlelatin"],
      a.data["content"],
      NetworkImage(a.data["image"]),
      a.data["sunlevel"],
      a.data["level"]);

  print(plantsitem.titlelatin);
  plantsmainnew.add(plantsitem);

}
```

Also just a suggestion if you use below structure for FutureBuilder would be more reliable I think:

```
          if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done)
            return YOUR WAITING ACTION;
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.hasData) 
              if (snapshot.hasError) {YOUR ERROR SCREEN}
            return YOUR ACTUAL SCREEN
```